# How to assign defined keyword as value of variable in Robot Framework? How to run a Variable as Keyword?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, robotframework, uiautomation

I'm currently using Robot Framework for creating UI automation for our project. And I would like to know how to assign defined keyword as a variable value and how to run variable as keyword?

Comment: For me it's unclear what you are asking for. You want to know how you can store a value from a keyword which have [Return] statement or you are asking something else? Please update you question with more details.

Comment: You should share the code to we understand and perfaps help....

Answer (score 0):

Robot framework has for this prepared keyword Run Keyword, where you supply actual keyword to run as a parametr - stored in variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a defined keyword as a value of a variable in Robot Framework using the `Set Variable` keyword.

For example:

```
*** Variables ***
${KEYWORD_NAME} My Keyword

*** Keywords ***
My Keyword
Log To Console This is my keyword.

*** Test Cases ***
Test Keyword as Variable
Set Variable ${KEYWORD} Evaluate ${KEYWORD_NAME}
Run Keyword If '${KEYWORD}' == 'My Keyword' ${KEYWORD}
```

In the above example, the value of the `KEYWORD_NAME` variable is assigned to the `KEYWORD` variable using the `Set Variable` keyword. And then the `Run Keyword If` keyword is used to run the `KEYWORD` as a keyword, if it's equal to `My Keyword`.

You can also use the `Evaluate` keyword to run a variable as a keyword, as shown in the example.